# calculate the percentage of data that are within the range in a given time space shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data base like this, but bigger.

```
  Indicea<-c(1,2,3,5,3,1,3,5,3,6,NA,2,1,1,3,2)
  Indiceb<-c(12,15,12,14,13,16,14,13,15,12,14,13,NA,13,11,12)
  Indicec<-c(100,NA,120,154,125,201,102,150,102,105,140,156,118,113,175,189)
  Especialidad<-c("gato","gato","gato","perro","perro","perro","perro",
        "buho","buho","buho","buho","tigre","tigre","tigre",NA,"tigre")
  Indiced<-c(0.1,0.5,06,032,0.1,0.25,0.23,0.12,0.15,NA,0.25,0.45,1.0,0.5,0.26,0.45)
  Fecha<-c("01/03/2020","02/03/2020","03/03/2020","04/03/2020",
     "05/03/2020","06/03/2020","07/03/2020","08/03/2020",
     "09/03/2020","10/03/2020","11/03/2020","12/03/2020",
     "13/03/2020","14/03/2020","15/03/2020","15/03/2020")
 data<-dataframe(Indicea, Indiceb,Indicec,Indiced,Especialidad,Fecha)
```

My ui is perfect
And this is a little part of my serve, I have a slideriunput that change acord the column. I need to do a table that group by "Especialidad" and count how many times the selected numbers in the sliderInput appear in the range and the percentage that it represents

```
   output$Rango<-renderUI({
req(input$SeleccioneIndice)
minn <- min(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
maxx <- max(BD9.3()[,input$SeleccioneIndice], na.rm = TRUE)
sliderInput("Rango",label = "Seleccione un rango", min = minn, 
max=maxx, value=c(minn,maxx))
 })
BD9.5<-reactive({
BD9.4<-BD9.3()
BD9.4$Intervalo<-NA
BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
(names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]>=as.numeric(minn),
"Correcto")
BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
(names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]<=as.numeric(maxx), 
 "Fallo") 
BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
(names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice )]<=as.numeric(minn),  
"Correcto")
BD9.4$Intervalo<-replace(BD9.4$Intervalo,BD9.4[,which
(names(BD9.4)==input$SeleccioneIndice)]>=as.numeric(maxx),
"Fallo")


BD9.6<-as.data.frame(table(BD9.4$specialty.name,BD9.4$Intervalo))
names(BDa4)<-c("Especialidad","Intervalo","Total")

BD9.6$Porcentaje<-NA

for(i in levels(factor(BD9.6$Especialidad))){
  
BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Porcentaje=round((
 BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Total/sum
 (BD9.6[BD9.6$Especialidad==i,]$Total))*100,2)
}

BD9.6 <- arrange(BD9.6, Especialidad, Cumplimiento) 
BD9.6


output$summary9<-renderPrint({
  BD9.6%>%
  filtro<-subset(BD9.6, Cumplimiento == "Correcto")
  print(arrange(filtro,-Porcentaje))
})
```

Comment: I don't think the underlying problem is related to shiny. It is much easier to help you if your example is minimal yet reproduces the issue. In this case, consider to strip everything shiny related and concentrate on the data wrangling part alone. It is much more fun to help if the problem is already boiled down to the real issue

Comment: @ErikaC  It's been 5 hours since `mnist` posted a very sensible comment to which 6 additional viewers have agreed. Part of the problem may be that your variables may have meaning in Italian, but not so much for native English readers.  You should break into 2 or 3  parts: first part (and not the subject of this question) is to verify that the input is a valid date; second part which appears to be the real question is how to take two dates and apply them to a dataset to return the right result, and the third part (also not part of this Q) might be to display the values.

Comment: The input is a valid date, actually it isworking very good, maybe I am not good explaining that I want. I so sorry, I am not good enouhgh. I will try again. I need select a rank whit the sliderInput and create a table that count  in a specifics dates how many was in that rank and that tell me the percent. Thank you and sorry for the mistakes